# Pass method from one file to another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Say in my first file, open.jsx, I have:

```
    // Default Import Statements here

var open = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          title="Test"
          ref="openDialog">
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  },
  _handleTouchTap() {
    this.refs.openDialog.setState({open:true});
  }
});

module.exports = open;
```

And in my app.jsx file I have:

```
const testComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
          <FlatButton label="Test" onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap}/>
    );
  },

  _handleTouchTap: function() {
    Open._handleTouchTap();
  }
});

module.exports = testComponent;
```

The error I am getting currently is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Open._handleTouchTap is not a function`

Does anyone know how I can pass methods in between files for React?

I want to call `open.jsx's _handleTouchTap()` method when they press the button in `app.jsx`.

Comment: Can you show us your component hierarchy please.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst i am just trying to create a simple application, only two layers right now: app.jsx and open.jsx. App.jsx has a button and when that button is pressed it should show the dialog within open.jsx

Comment: I think the proper way to do this then would be to create a non-react module that has the method, and pass it via a Mixin to both `open.jsx` and `app.jsx`.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I am trying to figure out a way to do this without mixins, just with react, I'm sure there's a easy way to do it but I'm new to the syntax which is causing me trouble

Comment: Well, still make a third component and just reference the component directly then. The only additional thing a mixin would do is automatically make the method available.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Open._handleTouchTap`, you are attempting to call the method as if it was static, on the `Open` class. This method, however, is only available once an `Open` component has been instantiated. You must attach a `ref` to the component and call the method via `this.refs.someOpenComponent._handleTouchTap()`.

You may want to provide more of your code so better examples can be provided.

Also, methods with an underscore in front of their names typically denote "private" methods, and should not be called from a different class. You may want to consider renaming this function so it is more clear what its purpose is.

Comment: I'm not sure what more code to include in this case. However, to try and understand better what you wrote, do you mean the method I included at the bottom of open.jsx?

`_handleTouchTap() {
    this.refs.openDialog.setState({open:true});
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to render some page with a button, and show the dialog as soon as someone presses the FlatButton. I also notice you're using material-ui, so let's go with that.

When starting any React project, it's a good idea to think about your component hierarchy. Because you're using material-ui and the Dialog component's opening is controlled by passing props, it's easiest to use the following approach.

### Simple case

Use a root component App (in app.jsx), which mounts a button and mounts a dialog, but the dialog is initially in a hidden state (the "open" prop on Dialog defaults to false) so doesn't visually show up yet (even though it is mounted). In this case, you will want the button to set the open prop on Dialog to true as soon as the button is pressed.

Please note I would recommend separating most of this rendering stuff into separate components; for illustration purposes, let's keep everything in App.jsx.

The way you want to organise in this case is as follows:

```
// App.jsx (render + handle click function only)
render: function() {
  return (
      <div>
          <FlatButton label="Test" onTouchTap={this._handleTapTestButton}/>
          <Dialog
            title="Test"
            open={this.state.dialogOpen}>
            <div>My dialog contents</div>
          </Dialog>
      </div>
  );
},
_handleTapTestButton: function() {
  this.setState({dialogOpen: !this.state.dialogOpen}); // flip the state
}
```

See? No refs needed even (and that's good!). Now, this works fine if your Dialog component is located nice and close to your FlatButton.

### More complex case: Dialog is far away from FlatButton

Your next question might be "**how can I organise this when the Dialog component is nested somewhere deep inside a totally different component that is not a child or parent of the App.jsx component**", but instead a sibling?

Well, this smells a little to me (just an opinion). It's not an anti-pattern per sé, but if you can avoid this, I would recommend you do. Ie: *for your own convenience and for maintainability's sake, try to keep components that naturally interact with each other close (in terms of parent-child) to each other in the component hierarchy*. This way, you can communicate pretty easily using props (see React's [info](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) on this. That's definitely not an absolute rule though, there are plenty of reasons to deviate from that.

Let's assume you have a valid case for not doing that, and even worse: the component are siblings, not direct or indirect grandparent/parent/child.

In that case, you have two options:

- Use a store and associated events (or any other javascript code that communicates state) to communicate the state change to the other component (ie using Flux, Redux, or whatever you prefer). In this case, when the button is clicked, you fire an event somewhere that gets picked up by the other component. This event triggers a state change in the other component. Warning: this can get unmanageable pretty quickly, which is one of the reasons state-managing-frameworks like Flux and Redux exist.
- OR, onTouchTap, have the FlatButton call a function that was passed down from a shared parent component. This function then flips the state at the shared parent component, and passes this state as props to the Dialog. Ie, when both components share a grandparent somewhere, you can define a function at the grandparent level and pass that function as a prop down to the FlatButton. The function's role is to change the state at the grandparent (dialogOpen). This state is then passed down one or more components as a prop all the way down the hierarchy until it ends up at the Dialog, which will auto show itself as the prop switches to true.

There are serious advantages/disadvantages to either approach. The first approach leaks your UI rendering logic into your stores (which is usually inevitable anyway, but can be managed using things like Flux), the second leaks it into the component hierarchy (tricky for maintainability) and tends to create tight coupling (yuck).